# WooCommerce - How to only show sale price if it is defined? Otherwise only show regular price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So, I have this code in my homepage for the featured products in WooCommerce, and it's working but the thing is I need them to hide the sale price if it's null or it's not defined.
Here's what I got so far:

```
<?php $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true ); ?>
<?php $sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true ); ?>
    <p>
        <del>
            <span class="amount"><?php echo wc_price($price); ?></span>
        </del>
        <ins>
            <span class="amount"><?php echo wc_price($sale); ?></span>
        </ins>
    </p>
```

I need a code that can check if there is a sale price and show:

```
<p>
    <del>
        <span class="amount"><?php echo wc_price($price); ?></span>
    </del>
    <ins>
        <span class="amount"><?php echo wc_price($sale); ?></span>
    </ins>
</p>
```

And if there isn't a sale price defined, only show:

```
<p>
    <ins>
        <span class="amount"><?php echo wc_price($price); ?></span>
    </ins>
</p>
```

Anyone can help me out with this??

Answer (score 3):

You just need to wrap it in some conditionals.  Something like this would work:

```
<p>
    <?php if(isset($sale) ):?>
    <del>
        <span class="amount"><?php echo wc_price($price); ?></span>
    </del>
    <?php endif;?>
    <ins>
        <span class="amount"><?php echo isset($sale) ? wc_price($sale) : wc_price($price); ?></span>
    </ins>
</p>
```

The initial if statement checks if there is a sale price, if there is, it displays the `<del></del>` block.
Then in the `<ins></ins>` block a ternary operator is used to control which price is output.

```
<?php echo isset($sale) ? wc_price($sale) : wc_price($price); ?>
```

Is equivalent to

```
<?php 
     if (isset($sale)) {
        echo wc_price($sale);
     } else {
        echo wc_price($price);
     }
?>
```

Comment: Was missing a parenthesis, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true ); 
$sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true ); ?>
<p>
   <?php if( $sale ) { ?>
    <del>
    <span class="amount"><?php echo wc_price($price); ?></span>
    </del>

    <ins>
        <span class="amount"><?php echo wc_price($sale); ?></span>
    </ins>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <span class="amount"><?php echo wc_price($price); ?></span>
    <?php } ?>
</p>
```

Just check sale price have a value

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot ;)